# jquery - img hover add style

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

i'm using the code below from http://webdesignandsuch.com/create-overlay-on-image-hover-jquery-css3/ to prepend a span to my images. the script works fine but i need more style-values to be inserted into the span.

```
 $(function() {
    // OPACITY OF BUTTON SET TO 0%
    $(".roll").css("opacity","0")

    // ON MOUSE OVER
    $(".roll").hover(function () {

        var s = $(this).siblings('img');
        var w = s.css("width");
        var h = s.css("height");

        // SET OPACITY TO 70%
        $(this).css("height",h).css("width",w).stop().animate({
            opacity: .7
        }, "slow");
    },

    // ON MOUSE OUT
    function () {

    // SET OPACITY BACK TO 50%
        $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

the img-markup is something like this

```
<span class="roll" style="height: 137px; width: 172px; opacity: 0;"></span>

<img width="172" height="135" class="img-responsive-rte" alt="" src="img/butterflower.jpg" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; float: left;">
```

is there a way to add the padding and foat values to the span?

thanks for your help

Comment: can't you just put it in the css like this `.roll{ do something here };`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `padding` and `float` next to other rules:

```
$(this).css("height",h).css("width",w).css("padding", "10px"). css("float", "left").stop().animate({
        opacity: .7
    }, "slow");
```

It's better to assign all css rules toghether:

```
$(this).css({"height":h, "width":w, "padding":"10px", "float":"left"}).stop().animate({
        opacity: .7
    }, "slow");
```

Comment: thanks for your instant help! this works, but because float and padding are variable, i need a way to extract it from the img-tag.